# Jmeter increase request per minute with a fix value

Tags: performance, rest, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Example I have 100 users and it generates 6000 request per minute. If I want to simulate the request with the request of 1000 request on the first minute and every minute it will increase 500 request minute until it reach to 6000 request per minute may I know how can I simulate this scenario?

1 min - 1000 RPM

2 min - 1500 RPM

3 min - 2000 RPM

4 min - 2500 RPM

5 min - 3000 RPM

6 min - 3500 RPM

7 min - 4000 RPM

8 min - 4500 RPM

9 min - 5000 RPM

10 min - 5500 RPM

11 min - 6000 RPM

seceding 6000 RPM

Currently I've tried Stepping thread group with Constant Throughput Timer and I'm having difficulties to simulate. Your response is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Thread Group you're looking for is [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/). It can be connected with Throughput Shaping Timer via [Feedback](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function) Function.

[image]

[image]

This way JMeter will be able to generate extra threads if the current amount is not sufficient for conducting the required load.

More information: [Using JMeter’s Throughput Shaping Timer Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin)